# Finding currentScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, overriding

**Here's a sample code:**

**HTML**

```
<script> alert('This is alert!') </script>
```

**JS**

```
window.alert = function(data)  //alert() over-riding
{
    scriptObject = document.currentScript; //gives me <script> object
}
```

**Update:** The above code doesn't seem to work now (*It worked earlier, [compatibility removed for IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript)*) in Internet Explorer 11.420.10586.0. <s>Why it is able to find the Script object in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Microsoft Edge, but not in Internet Explorer?</s> Is there any alternate way?

---

**Issue:**

**HTML**

```
<script> ReferenceError.prototype.__defineGetter__('name', function fff() { javascript:alert(1) }),x </script>
```

**JS**

```
window.alert = function(data)  //alert() over-riding
{
    scriptObject = ? // I need to get the Script object
}
```

I tried `arguments.callee.caller` to find `fff()`, but unable to catch the script object.

Alert() doesn't execute in Chrome for the above script. Use Firefox, instead. I couldn't get the script object in any browser.

Any solution please?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript#Browser_compatibility <-- look at the support table, doubt it worked in IE11 before.

Comment: Oops. IE got updated internally, may be. Is there any alternate way for IE?

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest scenario when your overridden `alert` is invoked immediately in (blocking) script, simple `document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]` could be good to go:

```html
<pre id="log"></pre>


<script>
window.alert = function(a){
 log.innerText += a + ' ' + document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1].outerHTML + '\n';
}
</script>

<script id="a">alert('first')</script>

<script id="b">alert('second')</script>

<script id="c">alert('third')</script>
```

Comment: This works in IE. But, if there are too many scripts, say, in your example, some 100 scripts continuously, will it be deterministic? I mean the order of data in `log`. Also, please have a look at the second part issue `ReferenceError` alert.

Comment: As long as those scripts will be static (not inserted dynamically after load as not-last script in the document tree) and synchronous (not async), yes, it must be deterministic and guaranteed to work properly: from the single-thread nature of JavaSript. (I'm not sure about async TBH.)

Comment: This cleared it. Thanks. Any idea about second part `ReferenceError` alert?

Comment: It seems a bit arcane to me, but generally I'd assume if you manage to override alert *before* the reference error override happens and is invoked, it should work the same. Dark prototype crippling aside, it is just call of some function, which, if redeclared in previous script block or file should be 'yours'.

Comment: Yes, the over-ride happens and is _invoked_. The issue is actually traversing from `alert` to `<script>`. Finding `arguments.callee.caller` doesn't help in this case, it's going somewhere inside `fff()`, and I could never reach `<script>`.